# Prove or disprove: $(A-B)-C=(A-C)- B$ for sets $A$, $B$, $C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Prove or disprove: For sets $A$, $B$, $C$,
> $$(A-B)-C=(A-C)- B$$

Now my attempt is

$$(x\in A \;\text{and}\; x\notin B) \;\text{and}\; x\notin C \tag1$$

We can write it as

$$(x\in A  \;\text{and}\; x\notin C)  \;\text{and}\; x\notin B \tag2$$

which proves the statement.

Is it right?

Comment: Don't forget to specify that $A,B,C$ are sets.

Comment: Yes it is right.

Comment: Your proof works by rewriting the set equation as a logical equivalence, and the mapping is straightforward. But doing this you don't really justify the claim but merely restate it. You should expand on the equivalence of the logical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the core of a valid proof.  All that is left is to tidy up the presentation.

---

The set of $(A\smallsetminus B)\smallsetminus C$ is the set of elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$ and not in $C$, which is one and the same as the set $(A\smallsetminus C)\smallsetminus B$.

---

$$\begin{align}(A\smallsetminus B)\smallsetminus C&=\{x:x\in A\smallsetminus B~\land~x\notin C\}\\&=\{x:(x\in A~\land~x\notin B)~\land~ x\notin C\}\\&=\{x:(x\in A~\land~x\notin C)~\land~ x\notin B\}\\&=\{x:x\in A\smallsetminus  C~\land~x\notin B\}\\&=(A\smallsetminus C)\smallsetminus B \end{align}$$

---

Or... whatever format you prefer.

Comment: I'll make the same comment as for the OP. This is a simple restatement of the claim, but the heart of it (swapping $B,C$ in the expression) is not truly explained.

Answer (score 3):

**A valid Venn diagram-based proof:**

[image]

---

This can equivalently be expanded to a proof of $(A\land\lnot B)\land\lnot C=(A\land\lnot C)\land\lnot B$ using a truth table.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set and $A,B,C \subset X.$

$A$ \ $B=A \cap B^c $(where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$ in $X$).

Then

LHS:

$(A \cap B^c)\cap C^c;$

RHS:

$(A \cap C^c) \cap B^c.$

Using associativity and commutative we are done.